# ZWCAD VBA Set Line Color

Tags: vba, autocad

I am need to set different colors for lines using VBA in ZWCAD.

In AUTOCAD I used this command:

```
Set AN = ACAD.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(p1)
AN.color = acBlue
```

what are the equivalent commands for ZWCAD?

Thank you

Comment: Interesting, which applications also support VBA. Did you already check the "Developer Help" with subtitles "VBA Developer Guide" and "VBA Reference" in your ZWCAD help (by pressing F1)?

Comment: Does it have a macro recorder? If the documentation isn't available (as suggested above), you can use the Object Browser (F2) in the VBE to inspect the object model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Set AN = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(p1)
AN.color = zcBlue
```

there are some differences between AutoCAD and ZWCAD. for example constants names start with 'z' like `zcBlue` while in AutoCAD we have `acBlue`

Comment: Thank you. I also noticed that just setting a number works, like AN.color=2

Comment: so maybe You would accept the answer? I like reputation very much ;) and I'm working with ZWCAD for 10 years, so maybe I would be useful? but just in the case of accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use colors by index number

```
AN.color = 5
```

instead of zcBlue

as you could find in https://www.engram9.info/autocad-2006-vba/changing-an-objects-color.html